# How to get case insensitive records from oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

How will I get all the `customer_names` starting from 'a' from `customer` table?

For this I want to get all the names which contain the letter `a` irrespective of case sensitivity. I don't want to use `to_upper()` because it will negatively impact query performance.

Comment: You search only for 'A'? or for any letter? or for any string?

Comment: Searching for letter 'A' will return many rows and any index won't be useful for performance. Are you sure you want index access?

Comment: I think your `to_upper` performance hit is small compared to the `%a%` search.

Answer (score 2):

If you are merely concerned about performance, you can create a function-based index

```
create index idx_fbi_upname
on
table( upper(name) );

select *
  from table t
 where upper(t.name) like 'A%'
```

This query can use the index on `upper(name)`.  Of course, if you want to do both case-sensitive and case-insensitive queries, you may end up with twice as may indexes which would involve more storage space and more work to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Getting names which *contain* the letter "a" is probably going to require a full table scan.  You can do something like this:

```
where name like '%a%' or name like '%A%'
```

or

```
where lower(name) like '%a%'
```

Under most circumstances, these will require full table scans.

If you are just looking for rows that *begin* with "a", then you can do:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.name like 'a%'
union all
select t.*
from table t
where t.name like 'A%';
```

This can make use of an index on `t(name)`.  However, this still may not use an index, because such string operations may not be sufficiently selective.

Comment: First approach is not correct for more than one letter. (Ex: aBc). Second approach will take time. Anything else?

Comment: @krishnapriya what is wrong with first approach?. The condition **will** get that string. Also, they are equal fast. There will be a full table scan.

Comment: @krishnapriya, answer from Justin Cave will work with any substring and it will be using the function-based index, so i would opt for this solution.